# 百年 - ヒャクネン or モモトセ

Tags: readings

When is 百年 read as ヒャクネン vs モモトセ?

Likewise, when is 千年 read as センネン vs チトセ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These days only ひゃくねん and せんねん are used.

In premodern Japanese it was basically acceptable to read any word with either kun'yomi or on'yomi, including people's names. For this reason you might see ももとせ in poetry or possibly as a brand name, but they would have to put furigana on it to make the pronunciation obvious. Google indicates that ちとせ is occasionally used as a place name or personal name.

Comment: I'm interested in what you said about premodern Japanese. Around when did that stop being acceptable? Do you have any references for more information?

Comment: The reading of normal words "either way" must have faded out in the Edo period, and I'm not sure how widely it ever applied -- the act of "reading" was itself a different thing in that time in ways I'm not an expert in. Personal names were often read either way well into the Showa period, though! I didn't believe this when I first heard it from a professor, but since then I've seen several instances.

Comment: By "several instances" do you have any examples? :)

Comment: Thank you for the question. While I was looking up the examples I remember, I learned that I had confused the information given to me, and what I was actually hearing about from my professors is a practice called 有職読み. http://lenguajaponesa.blogspot.jp/2009/09/lectura-yusoku-yomi-para-nombres-de.html

Now the question I want answered is, when 有職読み has been widely applied -- in library catalogs, for example -- which is the reading that scholars should use?

Comment: In case anyone is wondering about the varieties of reading in the Edo period, here's the dumbest example: every word in a sutra is 音読み, but every word in a norito is 訓読み. Yet they look fairly similar to those not versed in pre-modern literature. Wikipedia tells me that another type of reading, 漢文訓読, was standardized not in early Edo period but actually in the 13th century, so "pre-modern" is a very vague statement I'm making.